# Syntax for passing podAnnotations map to Istioctl installer

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to add some additional annotations to the pods that are created by the istiod deployment.

I'm using the [istioctl install documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/), which suggests that I can use the `podAnnotations` field from the [istio operator documentation](https://istio.io/latest/zh/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha12.pb/#KubernetesResourcesSpec), but I can't see how to structure the argument correctly.

The docs say it is of type `map<string, string>`. How do you express that?

I've tried a few variations, e.g

```
./istioctl install --set profile=minimal --set components.pilot.k8s.hpaSpec.minReplicas=2 --set components.pilot.k8s.podAnnotations={"foo":"bar"} -y
```

Comment: Which exactly annotations did you test and what were results? Did you see [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/)?

Comment: Why not use a IstioOperator resource instead of command line arguments?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I did see that page Mikołaj, but it didn't help to format the annotations when they're passed as an argument on the command line as shown in my example. I tried the example above, as well as some of the annotations I was actually trying to add (relating to logstash pipeline config). I typically got errors in the parsing of the command. It appeared to be showing a YAML document that couldn't be built based on my input.

I ended up resolving this as Chris suggests, with an IstioOperator resource. I will post more details as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this using an IstioOperator resource, which matches what Chris suggested in his comment.

To achieve the desired effect I used a resource which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: minimal
  components:
    pilot:
      k8s:
        podAnnotations:
          co.elastic.logs/enabled : "true"
          co.elastic.logs/processors.dissect.field: "message"
          co.elastic.logs/processors.dissect.tokenizer: "%{@timestamp}  %{level}    %{message}"
          co.elastic.logs/processors.dissect.overwrite_keys: "true"
          co.elastic.logs/processors.dissect.target_prefix: ""
        hpaSpec:
          minReplicas : 2
```

This file is passed to the installer on the command line:

```
istioctl install -f ${path.root}/k8s/istio/istioctl-config.yaml -y
```

This seems to be the way to provide podAnnotations. It also matches the recommendation made in the docs themselves to avoid using --set arguments on the install command in production.